# Equivalent method of System.out.println() rather than Log

Tags: android

What I want to do is to print a 2d array to the console, so the Log.d might not be convenient for that.
What are some other methods that work similar to system.out.println() in Android Studio?

Comment: `private final static String TAG = Classname.class.getSimpleName();`
`Log.i(TAG, "<information_string>");`

Comment: see `java.util.logging.Logger`

Answer (score 2):

`LogCat` is similar to console for displaying data.

For printing in `LogCat`:

1. Use `Log` class (eg: Log.d(), Log.i(), etc..)
2. Use `System.out.println()` this will print with TAG:`System.out`
3. Use 3rd party libraries like `Timber` or `Logger`

But all of this will help you to display, 1 item at a time; not the whole 2d Array.

For displaying a 2d array, you have to create a `custom` logging utility method which displays it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Timber* library. Example:

```
Timber.d("Hello %s %s!", firstName);
```